# prepare and bind to create SQL commands in javascript

Tags: javascript, sql, bind, cloudflare-workers

I'm having difficulty preparing and binding commands to be executed on an SQL database via javascript.

For instance, I'm using a D1 database from a Worker in Cloudflare.

The command I would like to execute is

```
INSERT INTO access(timestamp, user) VALUES (my_string_1, my_string_2);
```

*my_string_1* is a time stamp that I have into a variable like `my_string_1 = String(Date.now())` meanwhile *my_string_2* is another data I got with `my_string_2 = await KV_STORAGE.get(request.headers.get(PRESHARED_AUTH_HEADER_KEY));`

I can't understand how to correctly pack the SQL query, more preciously, what I have to insert in the `.bind()` method

I've tried

```
const db_response = await D1_STORAGE.prepare(`
    INSERT INTO access(timestamp, user) VALUES (?, ?)
      `).bind(my_string_1 , my_string_2).run()
```

but clearly, it doesn't work

Comment: You could use `try-catch` to print what error you got. Maybe you forgot to create that table?

Comment: @Firok the issue I was using Service Workers instead of ES Modules. In Cloudflare Workers fetching D1 database works only in ES Modules